# My dog swallowed a plastic bag of pie. What can I do?

Tags: dogs, large-dogs

My dog swallowed a plastic bag of strawberry pie. It seems to be a 10×10cm square. He swallowed on Monday morning, and today is Thursday. But he hasn't vomited or pooped it out yet. He is big dog, labrador retriever, and he is eating and pooping well now. But I'm worried about how plastic acts in the body, and I want to find the bag in his poo. What can I do?

Comment: Oh! He poop it today. 6 days after swallow. It's fantastic!

Comment: So glad to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

You should contact your vet, to make them aware.  The potential for emergency surgery is real.

As pointed out in this Q&A [Big hound has eaten corn cobs what can I do to help him pass them?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/big-hound-has-eaten-corn-cobs-what-can-i-do-to-help-him-pass-them)  as long as he keeps having bowel movements and is not gettting sick, he should be fine.  But if anything changes you will need to get to the vet as soon as possible.  Your Vet should give you more direction when you call them.